# C Makefile undefined reference

Tags: makefile

I have this project with the following file structure :

```
|-- CG.cu  
|-- Makefile  
|-- examples  
| |-- ex2.h  
|   |-- ex3.h  
|   |-- mmio.c  
|   |-- mmio.h  
|   |-- nos4.mtx  
|-- util.h
```

**CG.cu** is my main program (A Conjugate Gradient solver) i have some help functions in **util.h** and then i have some hardcoded examples in **ex2.h** and **ex3.h** (I know it's bad practice, but it's okay for now) the problem is that **ex3.h** need mmio.c,mmio.h and nos4.mtx to load in the example.

So basically the flow is : CG.cu -> ex3.h -> mmio.h (mmio.c) 
The compiler (NVCC : later being ported for cuda) complains about undefined references for the mmio functions.

Currently my Makefile looks like this:

```
main: CG.cu util.h
      NVCC -o main CG.cu
```

and GC.cu uses `#include "examples/ex3.h"`, and ex3.h uses `#include "mmio.h"`

Can you help me?

Comment: Please add the exact errors you get to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to compile mmio.c first, then link your CG.cu with the resulting object file.  You can do that in one step as well:

```
mian: CG.cu util.h NVCC -o main CG.cu mmio.c
```